# Exporting MATLAB surf plots with colorbars results in corrupted png files using opengl hardware renderer

Tags: matlab, opengl, plot, colorbar

When I export a 2D surface plot with a colorbar from MATLAB to a png file, it results in corrupted
images when I use the opengl hardware renderer, as seen here:

[image: corrupted surface plot png export from MATLAB]

Everything else is working fine. But after I created one figure with a colorbar, all
other surface plots that I export to png files are corrupted, even if they don't contain
any colorbars.

`opengl info` in MATLAB gives the following output:

```
    Version         = 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0
    Vendor          = Intel Open Source Technology Center
    Renderer        = Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop 
    MaxTextureSize  = 8192
    Visual          = 0x20 (TrueColor, depth 24, RGB mask 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff)
    Software        = false
    # of Extensions = 190

    Driver Bug Workarounds:
    OpenGLBitmapZbufferBug    = 0
    OpenGLWobbleTesselatorBug = 0
    OpenGLLineSmoothingBug    = 0
    OpenGLClippedImageBug     = 0
    OpenGLEraseModeBug        = 0
```

I tried all these OpenGL workarounds but nothing helped.

Has anybody an idea how to resolve this issue?

My system:

- Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic 64 bit
- Prozessor: Intel Haswell i7 4770K
- Graphics: Intel HD 4000
- MATLAB version: R2013b

On my colleague's computer, which is exactly the same, but has a different OS (debian wheezy) this problem is not appearing. On his computer `opengl info` gives:

```
    Version         = 2.1 Mesa 8.0.5
    Vendor          = VMware, Inc.
    Renderer        = Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x209)
    MaxTextureSize  = 4096
    Visual          = 0xfc (TrueColor, depth 24, RGB mask 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff)
    Software        = false
    # of Extensions = 143

    Driver Bug Workarounds:
    OpenGLBitmapZbufferBug    = 0
    OpenGLWobbleTesselatorBug = 0
    OpenGLLineSmoothingBug    = 0
    OpenGLClippedImageBug     = 0
    OpenGLEraseModeBug        = 0
```

Could it be that in his case it works because `Gallium/llvmpipe` is a software renderer in reality?

What's the problem with the colorbar?

Comment: How did you do the export that did not work? The `print` command?

Comment: @Raab70 Both using `print(...,'-r300','-dpng')` and using "Export Setup" from the figure's menu gives the same result.

Comment: Did you try it without specifying the dpi?

Comment: @Raab70 I tried every dpi (also auto) with every renderer, only zbuffer works.

Comment: every renderer? also `painters` (the only one which renders vector graphics)? - it doesn't work neither?

Comment: Sorry, I confused something. `painters` is working, the problem with the pixelated fonts disappeared after installing the following packages: ` gsfonts-X11`, `gsfonts-other`, `xfonts-100dpi` and `xfonts-75dpi`. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: It's unclear why do you want to use OpenGL? Also have you tried [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) from FileExchange?

Comment: Have you tried to use `opengl software` ? The images are not of that high resolution, but sometimes it fixes bugs.

Comment: Does the "File > Save as..." command work for exporting to PNG? For consistency you should provide code to generate a figure that results in this situation. Is it any surface plot when the `'Renderer'` has been set to `'OpenGL'`? Does the `colorbar` need to be present?

Comment: @Clemens: Yes, with 'opengl software' it works. My colleague has exactly the same computer, only a different OS (debian wheezy), and on his computer it also works with 'opengl hardware'.

Comment: @horchler: Wow. It's the 'colorbar'. Without it everything works just fine. After producing one single figure with a colorbar in it, I get corrupted png's for every other figure I am creating and exporting, even if they don't have any colorbar.

Comment: I am editing the question now to stress the colorbar issue

Comment: You could try to update your opengl by updating your graphics driver then?

Comment: I am using the most recent stable driver from Intel

Comment: See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#f64-504894). Does the `opengl('OpenGLClippedImageBug',1)` command fix this issue by chance.

Comment: @horchler: No, `opengl('OpenGLClippedImageBug',1)` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @GriffinPeterson Either it is another Intel gfx driver issue (there are quite a lot of them) or your OpenGL render window can not export data because of setting of rendering or device context during OpenGL window initialization (similar to trying print-screen video playback) try different driver or even software emulator like nwemulate (but I am not sure it works on Intel too)... to identify the problem more closely.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MATLAB isn't fantastic when it comes to standardisation, the problem with colour map is that when saved or not used with something other than MATLAB, the encoded image isn't saved or generated for easy use for other applications because MATLAB optimises the mapping for MATLAB applications only, if I do find an example that can help you I'll edit my answer but I hope this sheds some light on your problem.

Otherwise its matlabs fault and it isn't saving images correctly.